# Monitor all file actions of docker process

Tags: file, docker, ubuntu, process, monitoring

I want to run a docker container (under Ubuntu Server 18.04) with an env-file. The command is correct, but the output sais, it cannot find the env-file. So now I want to monitor the docker run process to see, where the process is searching for the env-file.

I already tried all thinkable variations of the path to the env-file. Also i tried it with a = between.

```
docker run -d --env-file config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file .config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file ./config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file /path/to/config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file=config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file=.config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file=./config.list [name]
docker run -d --env-file=/path/to/config.list [name]
```

At the moment, I already have set the whole path to the config file (/path, /path/to, /path/to/*) to 777 recursively. Just to be sure.

Output is always:

```
docker: open config.list: No such file or directory
```

The command
`cat /path/to/config.list`
works perfectly.

The container is runable when I leave out the env-file parameter. But useless, because the application acutally needs these environment variables.

Comment: Is your config.list palced next to the Dockerfile? That is where it should be. If it is in a different folder it will not be picked up even if you give it the full path.

Comment: @Mihai Since we got the Docker image from our supplier, we have no Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to choose another Docker Version.

In this case, I installed docker via snap while installing the server.
Then I installed it the "usual" way with apt, and now that works.